# Why is my array of arrays not being called when the $_SESSION is changed to TRUE?

Tags: php, arrays, session

I'm new to PHP and I can't understand why is my code not working as intended. I have two functions on a class controller, which one of them is supposed to be called when the user is logged out and one of them when the user is logged in. But what happens is the function is never called and I have no idea why. Only the function when the user is logged out is being called.

```
//index.php

    <!DOCTYPE html>

    <?php

        require_once 'Control/Controller.php';
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['logged'] = FALSE;

    ?>

    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <title></title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="mid">
                <div id="left">
                    <?php

                    if (User::isLogged())
                    {
                        $menu = Controller::initMenuUser();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $menu = Controller::initMenuGuest();
                    }

                    if (!empty($menu))
                    {
                        foreach ($menu as $item) 
                        {
                            echo '<li><a href="' . $item['url'] . '">' . $item['text'] . '</a>';
                        }
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

What should be happening is that on the div with id="left", there should be a different set of links and names depending either the user is logged in or not.

```
//Controller.php

     ...
     public static function initMenuGuest() 
        {
            $menu = array(
                array(
                    'url' => 'index.php?page=Login',
                    'text' => 'Login'
                ),
                array(
                    'url' => 'index.php?page=Register',
                    'text' => 'Register'
                )
            );
            return $menu;
        }

        public static function initMenuUser() 
        {
            $menu = array(
                array(
                    'url' => 'index.php?page=Profile',
                    'text' => 'Profile'
                ),
                array(
                    'url' => 'index.php?page=Cart',
                    'text' => 'Cart'
                ),
                array(
                    'url' => 'index.php?logout=true',
                    'text' => 'Logout'
                ),
                array(
                    'url' => 'index.php?page=Administration',
                    'text' => 'Administration'
                )
            );
            return($menu);
        }
```

Here is the method of the User class responsible to changing the $_SESSION['logged'] to TRUE. I'm calling this function on the Controller.php. if (isset($_POST['login'])) then call the function. $_POST['login'] is a form on the index.php

```
    //User.php
     public static function login()
        {
            $login = $_POST['loginl'];
            $password = $_POST['passwordl'];
            $u = new User($login);
            $res = $u ->check();
            $udb = $res->fetch_object();
            if (password_verify($password, $udb->password))
            {
                $_SESSION['user'] = $udb->login;
                $_SESSION['id'] = $udb->id;
                $_SESSION['logged'] = TRUE;
                $msg = 'Welcome '.$_SESSION['user'].' '.$_SESSION['logged'];
            }
            else
            {
                $msg = "Wrong Login information.";
            }      
            $res->free();
            return $msg;
        }

    public static function isLogged()
    {
        if ($_SESSION['logged'] == TRUE)
        {
            $res = TRUE;
        }
        else 
        {
            $res = FALSE;
        }
        return $res;
    }
```

Comment: Where are you calling the `User::login()` function?

Comment: @john-bupit It's on the Controller.php. if (isset($_POST['login'])) then call the function. $_POST['login'] is a form on the index.php

Comment: Try turning on error reporting. Add `ini_set("display_errors", "1"); error_reporting(E_ALL);`  on top of `index.php`.

Comment: Also, not related to the answer, but, you could simply write `return $_SESSION['logged'];` in the `isLogged()` function, instead of all the conditions you have.

Comment: I just added those two lines, but they don't seem to do anything when I run the code, should something be happening?
Yes, I guess I could make isLogged() simpler, thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `$_SESSION['logged'] = FALSE` in the third line of `index.php`. Regardless of the login status of a `User`, this line sets the value of `logged` to `false`, thereby failing the `User::isLoggedIn()` condition that follows.

Remove that line.

Comment: Done, unfortunately it still doesn't work. What happens now is that the User is always logged in even without writting the password :(

Comment: I think there might be a problem where you're calling the `login()` function. Are you calling `session_start()` there as well? Try `var_dump($_SESSION)`  at the end of the `login()` function to see what values actually exist in the session.

Comment: if I call the session_start() there again, a notice appears when I run the code saying that a session had already been started and it will ignore the new start_session(). And I just tried the var_dump($_SESSION) and the results are these: array(3) { ["user"]=> string(1) "r" ["id"]=> string(1) "1" ["logged"]=> bool(true)

Comment: Then the problem might lie in the `User::isLogged()` function. Could you post that?